# Show that the system $\ddot x+x\dot x+x=0$ is reversible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Show that the system $\ddot x+x\dot x+x=0$ is reversible

My attempt was to use a property from the book that if the system

$\dot x = f(x,y)$

$\dot y = g(x,y)$

is reversible then $f(x,-y)=-f(x,y)$ and $g(x,-y)=g(x,y)$.

I tried to convert the system into a system like the one above by letting

$\dot x=y$

$\ddot x=\dot y=-x-xy$

However, this system does not satisfy the second criteria, namely that $g(x,y)=-x-xy \ne g(x,-y)=-x+xy$

Is there another way to show that this system is reversible?

Comment: As a side note: I am not familiar with this property, but is it an if and only if? Should it just be an implication, from being reversible to the properties on $f$ and $g$, then it isn't conclusive to show it "can factor out" the sign.

Comment: I do not think that the property is an if and only if property. The more general definition given: a reversible system is any second-order system that is invariant under $t \to -t$ and $y \to -y$

Comment: Then let us use the definition. Consider some solution $x:t\mapsto x(t)$ and define a new function $\xi:t\mapsto\xi(t)=-x(-t)$, then $\xi'(t)=x'(-t)$ and $\xi''(t)=-x''(-t)$ hence $\xi''(t)+\xi(t)\xi'(t)+\xi(t)=\ldots$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, more general definition involves some mapping $R$ such that $R^2 = {\rm id}$ which commutes with the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the (very useful!) comments of @Did and @Evgeny in an answer:

The definition of *reversibility* I'm using is that of *time reversal symmetry*, i.e. the motion described by the system backward in time is equivalent to that forward in time (I'm following James D. Meiss, *Differential Dynamical Systems*, SIAM MM14, 2007, p. 212 here). That means that there exists a diffeomorphism $S$ that conjugates the flow $\phi_t$ of the dynamical system with its inverse, so that $(\phi_{-t} \circ S)(z) = (S \circ \phi_t)(z)$, for a dynamical system $\dot{z} = f(z)$. A bit more concretely in terms of the dynamical system itself: this implies that
\begin{equation}
 -f(S(z)) = D S(z) f(z).
\end{equation}
So, what's this diffeomorphism $S$ in the case at hand? Well, the idea is that we're looking for a coordinate transformation on $(x,y)$ that will give us 'the same' dynamical system as we originally had, before we inverted the time direction.

Inverting time, i.e. mapping $t \mapsto -t$ leads to the system
\begin{align}
-\dot{x} &= y, \\ - \dot{y} &= -x(1+y).
\end{align}
We now see that there's a particularly simple coordinate transformation that will return the original system, namely $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$. Using this coordinate transformation, we obtain
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= y, \\ - \dot{y} &= x(1+y),
\end{align}
which is indeed equivalent to the original dynamical system. That means we've found our diffeomorphism $S$, which acts as $S(x,y) = (-x,y)$. Note that, as $S$ is linear, $D S = S$. Moreover, $S$ is an involution, i.e. $S \circ S = \text{Id}$.

Admittedly, this is somewhat different from the 'usual' notion of time reversibility. In that case, the system would be invariant under simultaneously changing the direction of time ($t \mapsto -t$) and the direction of the velocity ($y = \dot{x} \mapsto -y$). This is for example the case with the ODE $\ddot{x} + \dot{x}^2 + x = 0$. Also, this holds for every Hamiltonian system.

Comment: There is a confusion here: the dynamical system at hand involves only one quantity, namely $x(t)$, and specifies that $x''(t)+x(t)x'(t)+x(t)=0$ at all times $t$, hence reversibility should be a property of the function $\bar x(t)=-x(-t)$ only, namely that $\bar x''(t)+\bar x(t)\bar x'(t)+\bar x(t)=0$. In other words the transformation involved is $x\mapsto\bar x$, and this *implies* that $x'$ is transformed into $\bar x'(t)=+x'(-t)$. Thus, in the $(x,y)$ coordinate, the fact that $y(t)\to y(-t)$ is not a choice, but a consequence of the fact that $x(t)\to-x(-t)$.

Comment: No, not really. Using the usual definition of a dynamical system (continuous time, differentiable), you can infer that this is written in the form $\dot{z} = f(z)$, $z \in M$ for some $n$-dimensional manifold $M$. So the proper way to turn the second order ODE in a dynamical system is to introduce a second variable, thereby turning it into a two-dimensional system of first order ODE's. That being said, the rest of your argument holds without question: indeed, it is even easier to spot the 'right' mirror symmetry from the second order ODE than from the two-dimensional dynamical system.

Comment: It seems you agree with my point, notwithstanding the first sentence of your comment. So, everything is well.

Comment: Everything is well indeed, I agree with your point.